# await not using current SynchronizationContext

Tags: c#, .net, synchronizationcontext

I'm getting confusing behavior when using a different SynchronizationContext inside an async function than outside.

Most of my program's code uses a custom SynchronizationContext that simply queues up the SendOrPostCallbacks and calls them at a specific known point in my main thread. I set this custom SynchronizationContext at the beginning of time and everything works fine when I only use this one.

The problem I'm running into is that I have functions that I want their await continuations to run in the thread pool.

```
void BeginningOfTime() {
    // MyCustomContext queues each endOrPostCallback and runs them all at a known point in the main thread.
    SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext( new MyCustomContext() ); 


    // ... later on in the code, wait on something, and it should continue inside 
    // the main thread where MyCustomContext runs everything that it has queued
    int x = await SomeOtherFunction();
    WeShouldBeInTheMainThreadNow(); // ********* this should run in the main thread
}

async int SomeOtherFunction() {
    // Set a null SynchronizationContext because this function wants its continuations 
    // to run in the thread pool.
    SynchronizationContext prevContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;
    SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext( null );

    try {

        // I want the continuation for this to be posted to a thread pool 
        // thread, not MyCustomContext.
        await Blah();

        WeShouldBeInAThreadPoolThread(); // ********* this should run in a thread pool thread

    } finally {
        // Restore the previous SetSynchronizationContext.
        SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext( prevContext );
    }
}
```

The behavior I'm getting is that the code right after each await is executed in a seemingly-random thread. Sometimes, WeShouldBeInTheMainThreadNow() is running in a thread pool thread and sometimes the main thread. Sometimes WeShouldBeInAThreadPoolThread() is running

I don't see a pattern here, but I thought that whatever SynchronizationContext.Current was set to at the line where you use await is the one that will define where the code following the await will execute. Is that an incorrect assumption? If so, is there a compact way to do what I'm trying to do here?

Comment: There's no guarantee that any thread switches will occur if the task (or other awaitable) has actually completed by the time you execute the `await` - always remember that the code may just carry on running past that point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a common misconception about `await`, that somehow calling an `async`-implemented function is treated specially.

However, the `await` keyword operates on an object, it does not care at all where the awaitable object comes from.

That is, you can always rewrite `await Blah();` with `var blahTask = Blah(); await blahTask;`

So what happens when you rewrite the outer `await` call that way?

```
// Synchronization Context leads to main thread;
Task<int> xTask = SomeOtherFunction();
// Synchronization Context has already been set 
// to null by SomeOtherFunction!
int x = await xTask;
```

And then, there is the other issue: The `finally` from the inner method is executed in the continuation, meaning that it is executed on the thread pool - so not only you have unset your `SynchronizationContext`, but your `SynchronizationContext` will (potentially) be restored at some time in the future, on another thread. However, because I do not really understand the way that the `SynchronizationContext` is flowed, it is quite possible that the `SynchronizationContext` is not restored at all, that it is simply set on another thread (remember that `SynchronizationContext.Current` is thread-local...)

These two issues, combined, would easily explain the randomness that you observe. (That is, you are manipulating quasi-global state from multiple threads...)

The root of the issue is that the `await` keyword does not allow scheduling of the continuation task.

In general, you simply want to specify "It is not important for the code after the `await` to be on the same context as the code before `await`", and in that case, using `ConfigureAwait(false)` would be appropriate;

```
async Task SomeOtherFunction() {
    await Blah().ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

However, if you absolutely want to specify "I want the code after the `await` to run on the thread pool" - which is something **that should be rare**, then you cannot do it with `await`, but you can do it e.g. with `ContinueWith` - however, you are going to mix multiple ways of using `Task` objects, and that can lead to pretty confusing code.

```
Task SomeOtherFunction() {
    return Blah()
        .ContinueWith(blahTask => WeShouldBeInAThreadPoolThread(),
                      TaskScheduler.Default);
}
```

Comment: Good point about the `finally` executing in a thread pool context, but I must strongly disagree with the recommendation of `ContinueWith`. `ConfigureAwait(false)` would suffice.

Comment: @StephenCleary: I do not know where `Blah()` executes. If `Blah()` executes on the thread pool, then you are right. But if it does not (e.g. if it is an I/O task, then I guess the task will be completed on an I/O completion port - but there is no guarantee either way), then the continuation would not be scheduled on the thread pool. The real puzzler for me, however, is why there is a need to control where the *continuation* task is executed.

Comment: The common conceptual model is that code either runs in a specific context (in this case, the custom `SynchronizationContext`) or "somewhere else". Whether that "somewhere else" is a regular thread pool thread or an IOCP thread pool thread almost never matters.

Comment: @StephenCleary: Yes, I agree. I will add an edit in that sense.

Comment: @JeanHominal: I want to allow a certain set of continuation(s) to run in the thread pool because it's not necessary that they wait for `MyCustomContext` to run them in the main thread (it would just slow down the sequence of steps). Your (and @StephenCleary's) .ConfigureAwait(false) solution worked perfectly, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I would expect your code to work, but there are a few possible reasons why it's not:

1. Ensure your `SynchronizationContext` is current when it executes its continuations.
2. It's not strictly defined *when* the `SynchronizationContext` is captured.
3. The normal way to run code in a `SynchronizationContext` is to establish the current one in one method, and then run another (possibly-asynchronous) method that depends on it.
4. The normal way to avoid the current `SynchronizationContext` is to append `ConfigureAwait(false)` to all tasks that are awaited.