# C# await in async method clears SynchronizationContext (with repro tests)

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await

Using Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 and a C# Test project targeting .NET 4.6.1 I get the following behavior:

```
[TestClass]
public class AwaitTests
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void AsyncRemovingSyncContext_PartialFail()
    {
        Log("1");
        SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(new SynchronizationContext());
        Log("2");
        HasAwait().Wait(); // The continuation in this method is on wrong thread
        Log("5");
        Assert.IsNotNull(SynchronizationContext.Current);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public async Task AsyncRemovingSyncContext_Fail()
    {
        Log("1");
        SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(new SynchronizationContext());
        Log("2");
        await HasAwait();
        Log("5"); // Issue is here - Sync Context is now null
        Assert.IsNotNull(SynchronizationContext.Current);
    }

    public async Task HasAwait()
    {
        Log("3");
        await Task.Delay(300);
        Log("4");
    }

    private void Log(string text)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{text} - Thread {System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId} - {SynchronizationContext.Current}");
    }
}
```

Here is the output:

**AsyncRemovingSyncContext_PartialFail**
1 - Thread 7 -
2 - Thread 7 - System.Threading.SynchronizationContext
3 - Thread 7 - System.Threading.SynchronizationContext
4 - Thread 8 -
5 - Thread 7 - System.Threading.SynchronizationContext

**AsyncRemovingSyncContext_Error**
1 - Thread 7 -
2 - Thread 7 - System.Threading.SynchronizationContext
3 - Thread 7 - System.Threading.SynchronizationContext
4 - Thread 8 -
5 - Thread 8 -
-Assert Exception Thrown-

I've done other tests and so far there is a 100% correlation between the existence of the `await` keyword in the method and the clearing of the Sync Context. This includes async lambdas.

This is important to me because it appears that as soon as an `await` is encountered, the sync context is removed. This means that if I perform two `await`s in the same method, the second continuation will just run in the thread pool (default behavior when no Sync Context).

**Is this a framework/compiler bug or am I doing something wrong?**

---

For specifics, since I'm sure someone will ask in one form or another, I have an [Active Object](http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/PDF/Act-Obj.pdf) that I would like to enable `async` \ `await` support for, but I can only do that if I can guarentee that the continuation will be dispatched to my `ActiveObjectSynchronizationContext`, which at the moment, it's not because it's being cleared.

I've already looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26227566/await-not-using-current-synchronizationcontext) (and similar about the UI context 4.0 bug) but this isn't related since I'm running 4.6.1 and I'm using non-UI threads.

I also followed the advice from [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16109936/synchronizationcontext-is-not-flowed-when-using-await) and ensured my Sync Context implements `CreateCopy`, but I can tell from test profiling that the method isn't even called.

Comment: _"am I doing something wrong?"_ -- it would help if you would explain why it is you think the [base `SynchronizationContext` class](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/synchronizationcontext.cs,8b34a86241c7b423) should be doing anything other than exactly what it's doing here. [The documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext(v=vs.110).aspx) seems perfectly clear to me: _"The SynchronizationContext class is a base class that provides a free-threaded context with no synchronization."_

Comment: It wasn't that the continuation was coming back on a thread pool thread (behavior of `SynchronizationContext` class), it was the fact that I set the Sync Context, I use await, and then the Sync Context is null. I first noticed this behavior using a custom SynchronizationContext, which then became null, and then would no longer get `Post` commands sent to it. I just used the default `SynchronizationContext` class as a minimum working example of the error I was seeing.

Comment: _"I set the Sync Context...and then the Sync Context is null"_ -- the context is per-thread (also documented). The context didn't "become null". You just wound up executing on a different thread from where you set it, as expected. And the context for that thread was null, also as expected.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Indeed, thanks. I've fallen into the trap of oversimplifying my problem in order to describe it. +1 for the context being per thread, I didn't completely have my head wrapped around that. In the real code there is only a single thread and the Sync Context dispatches to that thread. The issue with the real code was as Stephen said, I was setting the context in an async method and it was getting cleared after the await.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @StephenCleary mentioned in a comment, the issue was that in my real code I was setting the Sync Context in an async method but before the await keyword, which I thought would work but apparently it doesn't (I'm guessing the state machine grabs the context at the start of the method?).

The solution is to set the Sync Context in a **non-async** method first.

## Wrong

```
activeObject.Enqueue(async () =>
    {
        SynchronizationContext
            .SetSynchronizationContext(
                new ActiveObjectSynchronizationContext(activeObject));

        // do work

        await Task.Delay(500);

        // Sync Context now cleared
    });
```

## Right

```
activeObject.Enqueue(() =>
        SynchronizationContext
            .SetSynchronizationContext(
                new ActiveObjectSynchronizationContext(activeObject));
    );

activeObject.Enqueue(async () =>
    {
        // do work

        await Task.Delay(500);

        // Still on Active Object thread
    });
```

Answer (score 6):

`new SynchronizationContext()` [by convention](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg598924.aspx) is the same as a `null` synchronization context; that is, the thread pool context. So, the behavior in those tests is not unexpected.

`await` is behaving correctly; it is seeing the current synchronization context and `Post`ing its continuation to that context. However, the thread pool sync context just executes the delegate on a thread pool thread - it doesn't set `SynchronizationContext.Current` to `new SynchronizationContext` because the convention is that `null` *is* the thread pool sync context.

I believe the problem with your real code is that your `ActiveObjectSynchronizationContext` is not setting itself as current when executing queued delegates. It's the responsibility of `SynchronizationContext.Post` to call `SetSynchronizationContext` if necessary just before executing the delegate, although - correct me if I'm wrong - the name "Active Object" seems to imply a single-threaded STA-like model. If this is the case, then `Post` wouldn't need to set it; it would just need to execute the delegate on the correct thread, which should already have the correct current sync context.

If it helps, I have a single-threaded `SynchronizationContext` [here](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx.Context), though it doesn't do any kind of (explicit) message pumping.

Comment: Awesome, thanks Stephen! Indeed I was only calling `SetSynchronizationContext` once as the first command on the Active Object thread. I did not realize that it was the Synchronization Context's responsibility to also then re-set the Sync Context on each call to `Post`.

Comment: @MattKlein: If you do have a dedicated Active Object thread, you should only have to set it once when the thread initially starts running. The only gotcha is that it must be set in a synchronous method, not an `async` one.

Comment: That was the ticket! In my test code I was setting the sync context in an async method, but before the await, so I thought I'd be good to go. Thanks for clarifying, and for your book and blog!